# Sidebar width control R Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I've seen some topics here about changing the sidebar width but for former version of Shiny dashboard.

Here is my code for my ui. Seems simple on the documentation (http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#sidebar-width) but I don't have any clue why the titleWidth and width in dashboardSidebar arguments here are not working. Running this code bellow and nothing has changed.

Does somebody know why ?

```
  title = div(
    style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
    tags$img(
      src = "spf_logo.png",
      width = "20px",
      style = "margin-right: 5px;"
    ),
    "BS"
  ),titleWidth = 350
)


ui <- dashboardPage(title="BS",skin="black",dbHeader,
  dashboardSidebar( width=350,
    use_theme(my_theme),
    sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Guide utilisateur", tabName = "readme", icon = icon("circle-info")), 
    menuItem("Analyse Région", tabName = "sociodemo", icon = icon("chart-simple"),badgeColor="yellow"),
    menuItem("Tri à plat", tabName = "analyse_question", icon = icon("table")),
    menuItem("Dictionnaire", tabName = "dico", icon = icon("book"),badgeColor="yellow")
    ),
    br(),br(),  
    
    div(style = "margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 200px;",
        #h4(icon("calendar-days"),"Changer d'édition"),
        textOutput('year_edition')
        ),
    shinyDirButton(id="dir",label="Changer d'édition", icon=icon("folder-tree"), 
                    "Choisir le chemin vers la base de données",multiple = FALSE,buttonType = "danger"),
    
    textOutput("dir_selected")
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    use_theme(my_theme),
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without a reproducible example. My first thought would be that use_theme(my_theme) could be overwriting the width parameter, have you tried removing that?

Comment: Oh yeah thank you I thought of this but did not see that I putted use_theme twice... anyway I changed my theme to ```my_theme = create_theme(
  adminlte_color(
    light_blue = "#004192",
    red="#e30056",
    black="#3e3e3e"
  ),
  adminlte_sidebar(width=300)
)``` now my sidebar width changed howerver I don't know what can I do for titleWidth

Comment: Add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make clear what your (remaining) problem is.